# XSLT 1.0 Help Conditional Looping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement and below is the case ,

1. If Input Message Record is null then i have to populate with a empty value in OutPut Message
2. If Input Message Record is not null then i have to loop

Below is the two different Input messages :

Case one Input : Record is Null

```
 <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Correlation.Input1">
  <company>abc</company>
  <Token>1243</Token>
</ns0:Root>
```

Case two Input : Multiple Record

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Correlation.Input1">
  <company>abc</company>
  <Token>1243</Token>
  <Record>
  <Name>John</Name>
  </Record>
    <Record>
  <Name>Larry</Name>
  </Record>
</ns0:Root>
```

Desire OutPut For Case 1 :

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Correlation.Output">
    <Company>abc</Company>
    <Token>1243</Token>
    <Record>
        <Name>Default</Name>
    </Record>
</ns0:Root>
```

Desire OutPut For Case 2 :

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Correlation.Output">
    <Company>abc</Company>
    <Token>1243</Token>
    <Record>
        <Name>John</Name>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Name>Larry</Name>
    </Record>
</ns0:Root>
```

XSLT I have wrote :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://Correlation.Input1" xmlns:ns0="http://Correlation.Output" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
    <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="count(/s0:Root/Record)" />
    <xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v1) , &quot;0&quot;)" />
    <xsl:variable name="var:v4" select="userCSharp:LogicalNot(string($var:v2))" />
    <ns0:Root>
      <Company>
        <xsl:value-of select="company/text()" />
      </Company>
      <xsl:if test="Token">
        <Token>
          <xsl:value-of select="Token/text()" />
        </Token>
      </xsl:if>
      <Record>
        <xsl:if test="string($var:v2)='true'">
          <xsl:variable name="var:v3" select="&quot;Default&quot;" />
          <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v3" />
          </Name>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string($var:v4)='true'">
          <xsl:variable name="var:v5" select="&quot;fgfdg&quot;" />
          <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="$var:v5" />
          </Name>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="string($var:v4)='true'">
          <xsl:variable name="var:v6" select="&quot;fgfdg&quot;" />
          <xsl:value-of select="$var:v6" />
        </xsl:if>
      </Record>
    </ns0:Root>
  </xsl:template>
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp"><![CDATA[
public bool LogicalEq(string val1, string val2)
{
    bool ret = false;
    double d1 = 0;
    double d2 = 0;
    if (IsNumeric(val1, ref d1) && IsNumeric(val2, ref d2))
    {
        ret = d1 == d2;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = String.Compare(val1, val2, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0;
    }
    return ret;
}


public bool LogicalNot(string val)
{
    return !ValToBool(val);
}


public bool IsNumeric(string val)
{
    if (val == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    double d = 0;
    return Double.TryParse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
}

public bool IsNumeric(string val, ref double d)
{
    if (val == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return Double.TryParse(val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
}

public bool ValToBool(string val)
{
    if (val != null)
    {
        if (string.Compare(val, bool.TrueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (string.Compare(val, bool.FalseString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        val = val.Trim();
        if (string.Compare(val, bool.TrueString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (string.Compare(val, bool.FalseString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        double d = 0;
        if (IsNumeric(val, ref d))
        {
            return (d > 0);
        }
    }
    return false;
}


]]></msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looks like the http address for your ns0 namespace in your xml does not match the one in your XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://Correlation.Input1"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="ns0:Root">
    <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Correlation.Output">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="not(Record)">
            <Record>
                <Name>Default</Name>
            </Record>
        </xsl:if>
    </ns0:Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" >
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Mich , I am getting this error : White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead.

Comment: You must be using a non-conforming processor. Try removing the `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` line.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  Step through it in you debugger.  Let me know about questions. Add the formatting that you want.

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:Root ">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(Record[1])">
      <xsl:element name="Record">
        <xsl:element name="Name">
          <xsl:value-of select="'Default'"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Record">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Name">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="company">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Token">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is the error i am receiving : XSLT compile error. 'xsl' is an undeclared prefix. Line 1, position 2.

Comment: You use XSL in your code.  So, put this code in your existing style sheet command.  And, make sure you have the output command too.  If you like this approach you'll have to as the C# script too.  Let me know how it goes.